# MySQL Read Only when joining tables

Tags: mysql, join, readonly

I'm getting "read only" on the record results whenever I do a join select. I have full permissions as far as I'm aware (Insert, Update, Delete...). Only happens when I join tables, and I do have primary keys included in the select from each table joined. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please submit the query for evaluation, and if possible the details of tables involved. Table names, fields their data types etc.
Regards